# Can I login as an IAM user from Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Isit possible to login as an IAM user from Cognito? I am creating a tool that does AWS management functions and I want users to login as their IAM users ideally. Is this possible?

2 alternatives I am considering is:

- App will have its own IAM credentials and perform actions on behalf of app users. App will implement ACLs to determine who can do what (but this is implementing what IAM already does)
- Users will login via Cognito and inherit IAM roles, but its still having 2 "IAM users" (1 Cognito + 1 IAM user) for 1 "real" user

Of these 2 which is better and is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your purpose with AWS Cognito with the newly introduced user groups feature which allows you to assume different IAM roles to groups of users.

For the implementation if you go with AWS serverless stack you can use API Gateway IAM authorizer and pass through the role to Lambda to execute code with assumed role permissions. Another approach is to have different API endpoints to provide different privileges for AWS Management Access where you can authorize access through API Gateway using assumed role IAM policies(Policy to authorize API Gateway resource access). Here you can assign a different IAM role for Lambda.

Comment: So in this case I can share roles and policies but not the actual users?

Comment: Yes, users login through cognito will assume roles without sharing IAM users. You have to implement your handling of AWS API access for each user. On the other hand, if you need to directly allow users to login to web console, may be using Active Directory or etc, then you can do it without Cognito, directly using IAM Roles and federation.

Comment: @Ashan can you have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750010/control-role-permission-in-aws?noredirect=1#comment114484106_64750010