# Control role permission in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm new to AWS. I'm developing an application using Spring boot. I use `AWS cognito` for the sign in and sign up. I created a group called `ROLE_ADMIN` in **cognito** and connect with **IAM role** which was also created by me as `ROLE_ADMIN_IAM`.

I'm using `AWS Api gateway` (HTTP Apis, but similarly REST Apis) to communicate with Apis. **Then integrated the Cognito jwt authorizer in Api gateway.**

Everything working perfectly. The problem I'm facing now is, when a user sign in, I need to prevent few Apis based on his role which is in cognito groups. So I tried to attach policies to IAM role (`ROLE_ADMIN_IAM` already created), but it doesn't work.
This is what I attached to `ROLE_ADMIN_IAM`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-south-1::/apis/09bccr0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried restrict every resources also. But doesn't work

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm afraid whether the way I tried is wrong or correct? I've been working for days. But couldn't find any solution. Please anyone give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1.**

Since this doesn't work, I created a Identity pool and attached user pool Id and client id with it. It automatically creates two Roles for authentication user and unauthentication user. Then I went to Api gateway and changed the authorizer to `IAM`. The documentation itself says when we use `IAM` as an authorizer we need to use Signature 4 version. (I switched to **IAM** form **cognito jwt**, because I don't find any documentation or article say I can go with **cognito jwt** when we use Identity pool to define roles).

In the react application, I use amplify. When I configure Identity pool, it provides temporary Accesskey and SecretKey after a successful login. I tried to use it with postman -> Authorization -> AWS Signature, it always gives `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

Comment: Try to create another role and give the specific permissions required for that user. You cannot mix several policies in the same group. Use different groups and roles for the users with different permissions

Comment: I didn't mix any policies. I tried both after removing one.

Comment: Do you have your identity pool configured to use the role from tokens? If not it will always  role from the pool.

Comment: @AleksanderWons I didn't have, after your comment, I created. But it fails. Oncw I created Identity pool, it creates two Roles. One for Auth and another for Unauth. Then I attach that role in User pool group. But seems not working. Do I need any particular configuration?

Comment: You would need to narrow it down. It's hard to say what you did, how what and where could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a group in a Cognito user pool you need to attach proper IAM role to that group. IAM policy that allows actual API calls should look like that:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:a123456789/test/POST/mydemoresource/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You just need to replace demo string with your API Gateway ARN, method and endpoint. Pay attention to the "execute-api:Invoke" action.

Permission "apigateway:GET" does not allow you to call an API but to get service information about API. "apigateway:*" permissions allow you to make management AWS API call not actual API call.

For more information please check these articles:

[Management calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples.html)

[Execution calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html)